# Why does this ConcurrentHashMap stream only run half of entries at a time?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java.util.concurrent

I'm mystified by this curiosity. (I'm using ConcurrentHashMap rather than ConcurrentSkipListSet because the class doesn't implement Comparable.) I've got plenty of free CPUs on the computer and there is no difference between the classes that are run in the stream (other than random number generation). It's suspicious that the even numbers run first (consistently).

Here are the code and output with nRuns=10. I would expect all 10 threads to fire up and run simultaneously (as they usually do in my other uses of ConcurrentHashMap). Could it be due to some static code in LIBSVM that gets called by SvmCrossValidator? That's all I can think of. It seems to me from a basic Java perspective this stream should launch all 10 processes at once.

```
// instantiate and run nRuns times
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,SvmCrossValidator> scvMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i<nRuns; i++) {
    scvMap.put(i, new SvmCrossValidator(param, nrFold, inputFilename, nCases, nControls));
}
// parallel stream
scvMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(entry -> {
        System.err.println("SVM run "+entry.getKey()+" started.");
        entry.getValue().run();
        System.err.println("SVM run "+entry.getKey()+" finished.");
    });
```

Output:

```
SVM run 2 started.
SVM run 0 started.
SVM run 6 started.
SVM run 4 started.
SVM run 8 started.
```

LONG wait here while this first five grind away...

```
SVM run 8 finished.
SVM run 9 started.
SVM run 6 finished.
SVM run 7 started.
SVM run 0 finished.
SVM run 1 started.
SVM run 2 finished.
SVM run 3 started.
SVM run 4 finished.
SVM run 5 started.
SVM run 9 finished.
SVM run 1 finished.
SVM run 7 finished.
SVM run 3 finished.
SVM run 5 finished.
```

Comment: Perhaps you should link to explanations of what is LIBSVM & SvmCrossValidator?

Comment: Does it produce the same output on your machine when you use a ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map for example? When I use a String and not an SvmCrossValidator I get random output as you would expect.

Comment: Yes, Ivan, it has _something_ to do with the class in the Map values, but I wonder if anyone has seen this behavior -- it's rather odd that it does fire up 5 concurrent processes but not 10. I've not been able to think of any diagnostic to explain it. I've got other classes that I run in a ConcurrentHashMap which max out the computer's cores (128) immediately.

Comment: Basil -- I'd rather not go down the rabbit hole of what these actual classes are. I'm more interested in a general explanation if someone has experienced this: if you have some sort of class, ConcurrentHashMap will not run N concurrent processes even though there are many more than N available cores on the machine. (I don't actually _care_ about this issue, I'm happy to wait twice as long for the result, but I'd sure like to know why Java is behaving so oddly.)

Comment: But if you'd like to go there: LIBSVM: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ SvmCrossValidator.run() runs `svm.svm_cross_validation(prob, param, nrFold, target);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 2 things affect this. Firstly add thread name to your System.out to make the worker threads clearer:

```
System.err.println("SVM run "+entry.getKey()+" started." +' '+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

The system property `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` affects execute queues available to ForkJoinPool - see the constructor or javadoc for ForkJoinPool.

```
private ForkJoinPool(byte forCommonPoolOnly)
```

However `parallelStream()` creates a spliterator which I think also makes choices based on the size of the content which also determines no of streams - regardless of size of ForkJoinPool.

Changing java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism may not affect the outcome unless you make nRuns much bigger and it then uses more of the ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker threads.

So with a few tests on my machine:

- nRuns=10 never made use of more than 5 worker threads even with parallel=128, even re-used the same worker threads even though a lot more were available
- nRuns=1000 - reached around 130 at same time with parallel=128. Note that parallelism is not the value used for number of worker threads.

Comment: Excellent! Something that's annoying is that the first thread is actually the main thread, which seems a bit odd, you'd like the forked threads to be special-purpose:`[4]main
[6]ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-43
[2]ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-36
[0]ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-50
[8]ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-57`

Comment: Yes I was surprised to see that too, but I suppose caller / main thread is not going to proceed from the current line until all other workers are done, so is an efficiency to avoid kicking off an extra thread while main is waiting.